# probability that a variable, as a function of choice variables, is among the top k out of n when ordered

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, order-statistics

Suppose $(h_1,h_2,...,h_n)'$ is an $n\times 1$ vector.

Let $h_i=g_iX_i$, where $g_i$ is a choice variable which can vary across $i$ and $X_i$ is a random shock with Pareto Type I distribution.

$$f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
{\alpha x_m^\alpha\over x^{\alpha +1}},  & \text{if $x\ge x_m$} \\
0, & \text{if $x\lt x_m$}  \\
\end{cases}$$
What is the probability, as a function of the choice variables, that any given $h_i$ will be among the top $k$ largest of the $n$ $h$'s?

Thanks very much.

Comment: What does it mean "a choice variable". How  it  is distributed? How ANY given $h_i$ can be among top $k$ largest $h$'s.

Comment: $g_i$ not a random variable. It does not have a distribution. For example, suppose there are $n$ players, and each player $i$ chooses an effort $g_i$. The final outcome $h_i$ of each $i$ is subject to a shock $X_i$.

Comment: The question in this context is:

Comment: What is the probability that a given player $i$'s outcome $h_i$ will be AT LEAST the $k$th largest of the $n$ outcomes (ranked as either the largest, second largest,... or the kth largest)? Thanks @AlexanderVigodner